# Opengl ES 2.0 color array translucency ignored

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, translucency

I made a shader which uses a color array for the elements

```
private static final String VERTEX_SHADER_CODE =
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
        "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
        "attribute vec4 aColor;" +
        "varying vec4 vColor;" +
        "void main() {" +
        "    vColor = aColor;" +
        "    gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
        "}";

private static final String FRAGMENT_SHADER_CODE =
        "precision mediump float;" +
        "varying vec4 vColor;" +
        "void main() {" +
        "    gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
        "}";
```

Blend enabled

```
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Drawing as follows

```
    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        lineCoordinatesBuffer.position(0);
        lineColorBuffer.position(0);

        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        GLES20.glUseProgram(program);

        final int positionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);

        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
                positionHandle,
                COORDINATES_PER_VERTEX,
                GLES20.GL_SHORT,
                false,
                0,
                lineCoordinatesBuffer);

        final int colorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "aColor");
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(colorHandle);

        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
                colorHandle,
                COLOR_BYTES_PER_VERTEX,
                GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                false,
                0,
                lineColorBuffer);

        final int mvpMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "uMVPMatrix");
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);

        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 24);
    }
```

lineCoordinatesBuffer

```
493, 906, 533, 790, 483, 902,
533, 790, 524, 787, 483, 902,
76, 1513, 177, 1636, 83, 1507,
177, 1636, 184, 1630, 83, 1507,
988, 439, 928, 531, 996, 444,
928, 531, 936, 536, 996, 444,
950, 413, 905, 591, 960, 415,
905, 591, 915, 594, 960, 415
```

lineColorBuffer

```
-1, -1, -1, -122,
-1, -1, -1, -122,
-1, -1, -1, -122,
-1, -1, -1, -122,
-1, -1, -1, -122,
-1, -1, -1, -122,
-1, -1, -1, 97,
-1, -1, -1, 97,
-1, -1, -1, 97,
-1, -1, -1, 97,
-1, -1, -1, 97,
-1, -1, -1, 97,
-1, -1, -1, -110,
-1, -1, -1, -110,
-1, -1, -1, -110,
-1, -1, -1, -110,
-1, -1, -1, -110,
-1, -1, -1, -110,
-1, -1, -1, 72,
-1, -1, -1, 72,
-1, -1, -1, 72,
-1, -1, -1, 72,
-1, -1, -1, 72,
-1, -1, -1, 72
```

Output:

[image]

Expected output: the same but with alpha applied on the lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your upload of the color values is misconfigured. Shader color values are generally float values between 0.0 and 1.0, but you're uploading non-normalized byte values between 0 and 255. Any value higher that 1 is just going to get clamped to 1.0 on fragment writeout - i.e. in your scenario all vertices are fully opaque white.

Try setting the `normalized` parameter to the color attribute `glVertexAttribPointer()` call to `true`.